# Can't find a file in android folder

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying download a apk to update my app internnaly, so i'm using `DowloadManeger` and i'm saving in the download folder. The downdloading and saving are successful, but when i try to find the file, i fail miserably.

```
private fun downloadApp() {
    deleteFile()
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(updaterUrl))
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            "update.apk"
        )
        .setNotificationVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        .setAllowedOverMetered(true)

    val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    myDownload = dm.enqueue(request)

    registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))

}
```

I always check if the file exists to delete it, so I keep the same name for the file.But when i use `file.exists()` it always returns false, even though the file is in the folder.

```
private fun deleteFile() {
    val downloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val file = File(downloadFolder?.path, "update.apk")
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.delete()) {
            println("file Deleted :" + file.path)
        } else {
            println("file not Deleted :" + file.path)
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="br.com.exemple.anyprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
```

Asking permissions:

```
private fun haveStoragePermission(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.e("Permission error", "You have permission")
            true
        } else {
            Log.e("Permission error", "You have asked for permission")
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                1
            )
            false
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Permission error", "You already have the permission")
        true
    }
}
```

finally:

```
if (!haveStoragePermission()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE
                );
            } else updateApp()
```

And:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE) {
        updateApp()
    }
}
```

Comment: How about write permissions? Tell all you did. Android 10 device?

Comment: Thank you, @blackapps, I chose not even try the  getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) because was deprecated, but when i tried it worked.  Thank you again

Comment: If you want to use getExternalFilesDir() you should use setDestinationInExternalFilesDir().

Answer (score 0):

```
getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

That should be

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```